# Use the framework RSL within an RSL

Tags: apache-flex, rsl

I have a rather large Flex SWF and am breaking it up into separate Modules. There is some overlap between the modules and I want to put all of this into one shared RSL. The problem is that this RSL gets really large as soon as I use any Flex code because it has to include the Flex Library.

Flex Builder doesn't seem to give me the option to use the Flex framework RSL in a library. Also compiling with compc and passing the runtime-shared-library-path doesn't seem to actually use the rsl.

So it seems like this is something that is unsupported? Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? Is it just not possible? Is this something that is likely to be supported in the future or already supported in Gumbo?

I'm using Flex Builder 3 and the Flex 3.3 SDK.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the Flex framework libraries as "external" which will cause them to not be linked into your RSL.  You should also be using the Framework RSLs but those should be specified in your application settings (not your library).

Comment: Brilliant! Cut my RSL down from 350KB to 150KB.

Just added the following to my compc task.

<compiler.external-library-path dir="${flex3sdk.lib.dir}" append="true">
<include name="*" />
</compiler.external-library-path>